# Why pandas asfreq produces dates not in the input list?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a pandas dataframe, which is created using a list of dates as follows:

```
 date_list = 
 DatetimeIndex(['2015-02-06', '2015-02-09', '2015-02-15', '2015-02-17',
           '2015-02-18', '2015-02-21', '2015-02-22', '2015-02-23',
           '2015-02-24', '2015-02-25',
           ...
           '2016-12-22', '2016-12-23', '2016-12-24', '2016-12-25',
           '2016-12-26', '2016-12-27', '2016-12-28', '2016-12-29',
           '2016-12-30', '2016-12-31'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=547, freq=None)
```

Above list has 547 dates, which I'm using to create an empty dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=date_list, columns=list('ABCD')
```

I need the index frequency to be hourly, for which I do the following:

```
df = df.asfreq(freq='1H')
```

However, the resulting dataframe now has 695 unique dates, whereas expected is 547. Could anyone point what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: which pandas version? i cannot replicate

Comment: `asfreq` fills up the missing dates as well. E.g. while your `DatetimeIndex` doesn't have 2015-02-07, `asfreq` will automatically add the hourly frequency of that date, resulting `df` to have every day since 2015-02-06 to 2016-12-31, which has 695 days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your first two date as example

```
l=['2015-02-06', '2015-02-09']
df=pd.DataFrame(index=l,columns=list('ABCD'))
df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df
              A    B    C    D
2015-02-06  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2015-02-09  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

After `asfreq`

```
df.asfreq(freq='1H')
                       A    B    C    D
2015-02-06 00:00:00  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2015-02-06 01:00:00  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2015-02-06 02:00:00  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2015-02-06 03:00:00  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
...
2015-02-08 20:00:00  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2015-02-08 21:00:00  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2015-02-08 22:00:00  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2015-02-08 23:00:00  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2015-02-09 00:00:00  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
[73 rows x 4 columns]
```

Since you have date gap between `asfreq` will fill the that date with one hour , that will lead you have '2015-02-08' ect.

---

How to fix it

```
df=df[df.index.to_series().dt.date.astype(str).isin(l)]
```